# afnetworking differentiate web service calls when using in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, asynchronous, afnetworking

I am calling a webservice in for loop using AFNetworking.
I want to differentiate the response, i.e whether current response is for current index or other.

Is there any property for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager object so that i can differentiate each response.

I need to perform certain operations on some object from an array according to response, so i need to identify each response.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:requestAuthorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"guest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"user_type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"user_type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_os"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName] forHTTPHeaderField:@"device_name"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"ugx9gdispQMa6SwmwbWjz5ApDuqCfRENm2ATbCy6" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"AwwFiB7oEvYYZqAhPH0u9q8UozluVm110kVVrOHQ" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"guest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"user_type"];
    [manager GET:URL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);                              
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error code %ld",(long)[operation.response statusCode]);
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```